# How to collect HTTP response status using Genie.jl in Julia

Tags: http, julia, response, http-status-codes

How to collect the HTTP response status for a script?
Below is a sample code which will start a server and allow two routes for interaction.

```
using Genie
import Genie.Router: route
import Genie.Renderer.Json: json

Genie.config.run_as_server = true

route("/try/", method=GET) do
  (:message => "Welcome") |> json
end

route("/test/", method=POST) do
  data = jsonpayload()
  <body>
end
Genie.startup()
```

How to collect the response status like `200`, `500` or others as a string variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open connection to your server using `HTTP` and look for the status field:

```
julia> using HTTP

julia> response = HTTP.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/try")
HTTP.Messages.Response:
"""
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Genie/1.18.1/Julia/1.6.1
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

{"message":"Welcome"}"""

julia> response.status
200
```

If you rather want to control the status yourself you can add on the server side:

```
 route("/tryerror/", method=GET) do
     Genie.Responses.setstatus(503)
 end
```

And now let us test it for `503`:

```
julia> response = HTTP.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/tryerror")
ERROR: HTTP.ExceptionRequest.StatusError(503, "GET", "/tryerror", HTTP.Messages.Response:
"""
HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable
Content-Type:
Server: Genie/1.18.1/Julia/1.6.1
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

""")
```

Comment: Thanks @PrzemyslawSzufel for this amazing solution, highly appreciate it !!